# Compiled and modified source wont work with server=1

Tags: bitcoin-core, dogecoin

I just compiled dogecoin-qt using the original source, and edited it to generate new genesis block, because i want to create new coin for educational purpose. It is working just fine, and without an error, but whenever i try to crate a conf file in %appdata%\dogecoin\dogecoin.conf with this content

> rpcuser=abc
>   rpcpassword=abcd
>   rpcport=22565
>   server=1
>   daemon=1
>   listen=1

It will say

> "To use the -server options you must setup a secure rpcpassword in configuration file at xxxxx\Dogecoin\dogecoin.conf rpcuser=xx
>   rpcpass=xxxxxxxxx

this an error that should only appear if i used server=1 in conf file, but dont provide rpcuser and pass. but i am already providing that.

I am looking for someones help to get me to understand what I am doing wrong. And sorry if this doesn't belong here.

Comment: If you're modifying the source code, then you're programming. Use your debugger and put a breakpoint on the message you get and find out how it got there. We can't really help you because we don't know what you have modified.

Comment: @GregHewgill 
http://pastebin.com/YnBWT7L1

I ran dogecoin-qt with --debug from cmd, and saved this debug. Please have a look. I see that it says
2014-02-24 18:23:01 Bound to [::]:33465
2014-02-24 18:23:01 Bound to 0.0.0.0:33465

it should write 127.0.0.1, right?
I did not modify code at all, other than changing the genesis block and modifying the total number of coins, coins per block etc.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. Address 0.0.0.0 means it's listening on *all* interfaces, not just 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @GregHewgill could this be a reason that I mined genesis block by using testnet feature of the coin, then added the genesis block hash and merkle hash to the coin's source code, and compiled again. And that is why the coin has this problem? Because I have heard some problem with bitcoin where if you run bitcoin -testnet. you have to paste the bitcoin.conf to %appdata%\bitcoin\testnet\bitcoin.conf or %appdata%\bitcoin\testnet.conf
could that be an issue?

Comment: @GregHewgill thank you for the link of that thread. yes, i have the same issue with dogecoin-qt and dogecoind. on that thread, no one was able to help them out.

Comment: @GregHewgill yes, posted my answer to my own question for others help.

Comment: @GregHewgill but can you help me to setup dogecoin to use a smaller password like all the other coins like litecoin, feathercoin etc. I want to use a password like rpcpassword=abcd

Comment: You're already editing the source code. Change the `weakPassword()` function such that it meets your relaxed complexity requirements.

Comment: @GregHewgill you have been a great help. Would you answer my other question regarding setting up a node as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with version 1.5  of dogecoin.I fixed it by using this long password.

rpcpassword=DLKKWE93203909238dkkKKeowxmIOw0232lsakwL02k

to solve the problem. Change the password to whatever you want, just use lowercase, upper case and letters, it should fix the problem